# Can you generate a static site with nuxt fetching data from strapi during build time? I am having issues

Tags: nuxt.js, strapi

I am new to both nuxt and strapi so I'm not sure what I've missed.

I am trying to create a fully static site which makes all the api calls to my localhost strapi server to fetch the data during build. Unfortunately each time I run nuxt generate and try and host the contents of the /dist file, the site makes live get requests to the api on the client side which breaks the site when not on my local machine.

In my nuxt.config.js I have my target:"static" which is all I thought I'd have to do but I am probably incorrect. I am wondering if I need to host my api in order to make this work but would really rather not do this.

I have been using fetch to get my data.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong? Very grateful for any help on the subject.

EDIT:

I wondered if there was a problem with my set up so I created a new nuxt and strapi setup with test content and found the same problem. I'm wondering now if I shouldn't be using fetch in my page components and should be using asyncData instead? The documentation definitely says fetch should be fine, so I'm trying to work out what's going on.

Further EDIT:

Not fixed, but making progress in the right direction I think. It appears that I should have been setting the routes variable in the generate variable in nuxt.config.js in order to build out my dynamic pages. However, I am still unable to view all of the images for each product... about to try using require() with the image tags in the templates.

Comment: Do you want to push and your app to build on Netlify (or alike) or do you want to always build your app locally and then manually push the `/dist` directory?

Comment: The content rarely changes so I was hoping to build my app locally and then manually push /dist to host it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch()` is totally fine to get the content because it will run both on server and client side. If you do use Nuxt's dynamic routes, it should generate it properly. As for the images, I'm not sure (didn't tried yet) but this can totally be done during the build time too.
You can generate the pages without having to go to `nuxt.config.js` to my knowledge.

Last time I worked with Strapi, I tried to run the starter linked in this article and it was working flawlessly: https://strapi.io/blog/build-a-blog-using-nuxt-strapi-and-apollo

As of your build, if you plan to build it locally, you will totally be okay with hosting it afterwards. A quick `yarn start` could confirm that your project is working great.
Meanwhile, you will need to be 100% sure that you are not planning on using your Strapi project again for further (client side) fetching. Should be fine by default IMO.

Comment: Thank you! It is good to know that at least what I'm trying to do should work. From what I can tell it is only the images which don't come through when I generate the site. The rest of the api data comes through fine. I'm going to look at the link with apollo and see if I can find something there to make it work

Comment: @kissu   Any success? I need to deploy the whole website to the CDN, with automatic deploys.